# The file is not a Revit file or is not a supported version

Tags: autodesk-forge

I upload a '.rvt' file by postman.And translate to svf. But it response me translated failed message. My rvt file built by Revit2017.

uploaded response:
[image]

And I call manifest. It response me:

```
{
"type": "manifest",
"hasThumbnail": "false",
"status": "failed",
"progress": "complete",
"region": "US",
"urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0_____________6Ym9pbGVyL1JWTW9kZWwucnZ0",
"version": "1.0",
"derivatives": [
    {
        "name": "LMV Bubble",
        "hasThumbnail": "false",
        "status": "failed",
        "progress": "complete",
        "messages": [
            {
                "type": "error",
                "message": "Possibly recoverable warning exit code from extractor: -536870935",
                "code": "TranslationWorker-RecoverableInternalFailure"
            },
            {
                "type": "error",
                "code": "Revit-UnsupportedFileType",
                "message": "<message>The file is not a Revit file or is not a supported version.</message>"
            }
        ],
        "outputType": "svf"
    }
]}
```

Have I missed step? Is my file wrong?

Comment: To easily eliminate whether there's an error in your postman setup or your file, first try and log in with your Key and Secret here: https://models.autodesk.io and then drag and drop your revit file to upload and translate it. If your file isn't corrupt, you'll then be able to open it in the viewer from there

Comment: And you can also try it at https://a360.autodesk.com to see if the file is ok. Please share what you found. The translation engine supports Revit 2017 files.

Comment: any news from your side?

Comment: I found the problem is on upload api. My file seems damage or too large. And I have to use uploadChunk not uploadObject. The original problem is "upload phase" not "translate phase". I follow https://github.com/jaimerosales/modelderivative-nodejs-tutorial